# PreferenceActivity not associated with "Settings"

Tags: android, android-layout

I have my simple PreferenceActivity class and its onCreate passes my `R.xml.preferences` screen to `((PreferenceActivity)super).addPreferencesFromResource`.  Finally, in my AndroidManifest.xml my activity as follows:

```
<activity android:name="com.criticalrf.jwalkietalkie.PreferenceServerActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MANAGE_NETWORK" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

On the device, the menu button will trigger a menu with only the word "Settings."  Clicking on Settings makes the Settings button go away but does not show anything.  Do I need to add something in my MainActivity?  I followed this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html), I'm not sure what I missed.

Comment: Is your activity starting? I mean do you call startActivity for your PreferenceServerActivity?

Comment: No, I don't see startActivity in the guide.  I'm not sure how I would even get a reference to PreferenceServerActivity.

Comment: Well in tutorial its this: 'Thus, when the user inspects how much data your app is using from the system's Settings app, a View application settings button is available that launches your PreferenceActivity so the user can refine how much data your app uses.' So it will not appear directly in system settings, but only at data usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open this preference activity from your main activity you should call somewhere in your MainActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferenceServerActivity.class));
```

and preference activity will show.

Typical implementation would be doing it with options menu. Like:

```
    private static final int SettingsId = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add(0, SettingsId, 0, "Settings");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case SettingsId:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferenceServerActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Intent filter in your manifest from tutorial just says, that this activity can be opened from system settings when user browse data usage of your app.

Comment: I thought the build-in settings menu would start the activity.  I do have it defined in `AndroidManifest.xml.`  I did include your example in my main onCreate method, the app is just crashing now and leaving me no clue as to why.

Comment: Well, I guess there will be problem in settings activity. Check your logcat and try to debug your reference activity.

Comment: Wow, this was not mentioned anywhere in the guide.  I'm so happy, I'm seeing new problems now ;-)... Google needs to hire you.  Thank you.